# Migrar dados da coluna de uma tabela para uma outra coluna de outra tabela

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, mysql

Trabalho em uma empresa onde implementamos uma funcionalidade nova em nosso sistema, porem, anteriormente um campo da nossa tabela era `bug_passos varchar(500)`, agora com a nova implementação, criamos uma nova tabela com os seguintes campos `bugp_id bigint(20), bugp_titulo varchar(500) e bugp_ordem int(4)`.

Gostaria de saber como que eu faço para migrar os dados antigos da coluna `bug_passos` que e de uma outra tabela para esta nova tabela. Alguém me daria uma luz?

Tabela Antiga:

```
`CREATE TABLE `tb_bug` (
  `bug_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bug_id_tenancy` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_data_criacao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_data_atualizacao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_descricao` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_passos` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_status` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_fase` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_gravidade` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_titulo` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_informacoes_gerais` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_pro_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_usu_id_criador` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_emp_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_tipo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_usu_id_executor` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_dem_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bug_prioridade` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bug_id`),
  KEY `bug_pro_id` (`bug_pro_id`),
  KEY `bug_usu_id_criador` (`bug_usu_id_criador`),
  KEY `bug_emp_id` (`bug_emp_id`),
  KEY `bug_usu_id_executor` (`bug_usu_id_executor`),
  KEY `bug_dem_id` (`bug_dem_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_bug_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bug_pro_id`) REFERENCES `tb_projeto` (`pro_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_bug_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`bug_usu_id_criador`) REFERENCES `tb_usuario` (`usu_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_bug_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`bug_emp_id`) REFERENCES `tb_empresa` (`emp_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_bug_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`bug_usu_id_executor`) REFERENCES `tb_usuario` (`usu_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tb_bug_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`bug_dem_id`) REFERENCES `tb_demanda` (`dem_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2807 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

Tabela Atual

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_bug_passo` (
  `bugp_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bugp_titulo` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bugp_bug_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `bugp_ordem` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bugp_id`),
  KEY `fk_bug_passos` (`bugp_bug_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bug_passos` FOREIGN KEY (`bugp_bug_id`) REFERENCES `tb_bug` (`bug_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18767 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Parece que os dados da nova tabela estará separado seguindo alguns critérios. Você pode montar uma procedure e com alguns cursores seleciona os dados de uma tabela e insere na outra seguindo os critérios pré estabelecidos.

Comment: Sera que você poderia me dar um exemplo de procedure que funcionaria para este caso, ja dei uma pesquisada e não consegui encontrar nada meio parecido :/ estou um pouco desesperado com esta tarefa já kkkk

Comment: Não é só fazer um select into?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Primeiro é preciso nos informar se vc pretende fazer um insert ou um update. É muito diferente, quando você quer cadastrar dados de uma tabela para outra tabela, ou se vc quer atualizar apenas um campo novo vazio que possua dados pré-existentes na tabela nova.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Pretendo atualizar os dados da  coluna de uma nova tabela, porém, os dados que eu pretendo inserir já existem na coluna de uma outra tabela. Quando eu fiz o `insert into` retornou que o  `bugp_bug_id` que é a minha chave de ligação entre as duas tabelas não possui um valor default.

`INSERT INTO
 tb_bug_passo(bugp_titulo) SELECT  bug_passos
FROM
    tb_bug
`

Comment: Então, neste caso, se vc já tem os outros dados, não precisa mais de insert, é update. Tente usar uma subquery para fazer update.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc está fazendo uma tabela auxiliar, correto...  que relaciona n ... n, e precisa importar os dados relacionais para esta tabela, é isso?

Comment: @IvanFerrer Exatamente isso...

Comment: Vc não pode usar auto_increment no campo ID que irá importar as chaves auto_increment para esta tabela auxiliar... deve ser um campo numérico... vc pode até fazer uma relação de update entre as duas, tipo, se uma atualizar, a auxiliar atualiza tb..., só não recomendo fazer o delete.

Comment: Certo, vou tentar fazer o Update aqui. Se der certo vc me salvou hehe vlw pela paciência, sou bem inexperiente com BD.

Comment: Então, deixa essa tabela vazia, ela até pode ter uma auto_increment, mas não deve ser a mesma ID da tabela antiga, passa a ser um chave estrangeira (foreign_key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into TB_NEW (field_new) select field_old from TB_OLD;
```

lembrando que a mesma quantidade de colunas no insert tem que ser igual no select, e a ordem também, caso precise refinar mais os dados, use o `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte SQL:

```
   INSERT INTO
    tb_bug_passo (bugp_bug_id, bugp_titulo) 
SELECT 
    bug_id, bug_passos
FROM 
    tb_bug
```

Tbm fiz uma Stored Procedure que inseriu a ordem para mim separada.

Comment: A resposta do @godoyAlexandre é exatamente o que você fez, a diferença é que ele fez um exemplo minimalista.